# Mathematica replaces list of zeros with zero

Tags: functions, matrix, map

Consider the following functions:

```
f[x_]:= {{Im[x], Re[x]}, {Re[x], Im[x]}};

g[x_]:= {{Im[x],0},{0,0}}
```

When applying each of the functions to the list of lists `{{1,2,3}}`, it yields the results

```
{{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}}}

{{{{0, 0, 0}, 0}, {0, 0}}}
```

The problem with the second solution is that some entries are numbers, i.e. 0, even though they should be lists.

Considering that I wish to use something like `f /@ listoflists` (which means I cannot simply edit each of the lists): how can I obtain a result where instead of 0 there is a list of 0s for all entries of the matrix?

Edit: fixed some typos and made the objective clearer.

Comment: What do you want for an answer to `g[{{1,2,3}}]`?

Comment: @MikeY exactly the same form as if f was used, but with a list of 0s instead of just 0

Comment: @MikeY I edited the original post. Hope it makes it clearer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy way...keep stucture of `f[ ]`

```
g[x_] := {{Im[x], 0 Re[x]}, 0 {Re[x], Im[x]}};


g[{{1, 2, 3}}]

(* {{{{0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}}}} *)
```

Comment: Damn, inexperience really shows in these situations. Thank you kindly!